# XPath to Extract Items from RSS Feed in XML Data Source for SSRS

Tags: xml, reporting-services

I am using JIRA to retrieve xml from a web service in SSRS with an XML data source.

My XML looks like this

```
<rss version="0.92">
<channel>
   <title>...</title>
   <link>http:/jira/issues/?filter=14905</link>
   ...
<item>
   <title>[MYPROJ-226] Sample Issue 1</title>
   <link>http://jira/browse/MYPROJ-226</link>
    ...
</item>
<item>
   <title>[MYPROJ-227] Sample Issue 2</title>
   <link>http://jira/browse/MYPROJ-227</link>
    ...
</item>
<item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

I cannot find the `ElementPath` to select details from the items, i.e. to select

```
Sample Issue 1
Sample Issue 2
```

I have tried

```
<Query>
  <ElementPath>rss{}/channel{}/item{title}</ElementPath>
</Query>
```

And variations but it doesn't produce any results. What ElementPath should I use?

Comment: In fact this expression ss{}/channel{}/item{title} now seems to crash SSRS - it gets stuck refreshing the query (there are 49 docs in the xml so it's not massive)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! It was a problem with the authentication on the query. Remember that when testing through a browser, it will be logged into JIRA, when testing through SSRS, it won't be. I needed to use Windows Authentication on the connection to get the items populated.